# How to return only one field in tastypie?

Tags: django, json, tastypie

Suppose I have a resource like below..

```
class PostResource(ModelResource):

    children = fields.ToManyField('MyApp.api.resources.PostResource',
                 attribute='comments', full=True, null=True)
```

Basically, I want to return this children field only and flatten it.

It will look like
`[ {child-1-data}, {child-2-data} ]`
rather than
`{ children: [ {child-1-data}, {child2-data} ] }`

How can I do that?

Additionaly, if I want a different representation of the same model class, should I create a new resource class as bellow?

```
class PostNormalResource(ModelResource):
      class Meta:
          queryset= models.Post.objects.all()
          fields = ['text', 'author']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer you are looking for but some discoveries I made while digging.

Normally you would modify the bundle data in `dehydrate`. See the [tastypie cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#adding-custom-values).

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['custom field'] = "This is some additional text on the resource"
    return bundle
```

This would suggest you could manipulate your `PostResource`'s bundle data along the lines of:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    # Replace all data with a list of children
    bundle.data = bundle.data['children']
    return bundle
```

However this will error, `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`, as the tastypie serializer is looking to serialize a dictionary not a list.

```
# "site-packages/tastypie/serializers.py", line 239
return dict((key, self.to_simple(val, options)) for (key, val) in data.data.items())

# .items() being for dicts
```

So this suggests you need to look at different serializers. (Or just refer to `post['children']` when processing your JSON :-)

Hope that helps get you in the right direction

---

And secondly yes, if you want a different representation of the same model then use a second `ModelResource`.  Obviously you can subclass to try and avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the `alter_detail_data_to_serialize` method. It it called right after whole object has been dehydrated, so that you can do modifications on the resulting dictionary before it gets serialized.

```
class PostResource(ModelResource):
    children = fields.ToManyField('MyApp.api.resources.PostResource',
             attribute='comments', full=True, null=True)

    def alter_detail_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
        return data.get('children', [])
```

As to different representation of the same model - yes. Basically, you shouldn't make a single `Resource` have many representations as that would lead to ambiguity and would be difficult to maintain.